# Why PhpMailer failes on some machines?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails. My problem is that from my PC everything works just fine, but on other devices, like someone else laptop or PC gives the following error:

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.The following From address failed: confidential@confidential.com Mailer Error: The following From address failed: confidential@confidential.com
```

SMTP server error: AUTH command used when not advertised

Can someone give some light on this one please?!

My code:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = stripslashes($_POST['textarea']);
$body = str_replace('&nbsp;',' ',$body);
$body = str_replace('/media/','http://www.confidential.com/media/', $body);
$body = $body;

//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

    $mail->From       = "confidential@confidential.com";
    $mail->FromName   = "confidential confidential";
    $mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Subject    = $_POST['subject'];
    //$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    //$mail->Host       = "confidential.com"; // SMTP server    
    //$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;                  // enable SMTP authentication 
    //$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    //$mail->Username   = "confidential@confidential.com"; // SMTP account username
    //$mail->Password   = "confidential";        // SMTP account password
    $mail->SetFrom('confidential@confidential.com', 'confidential confidential');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("confidential@confidential.com","confidential confidential");     
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

Furthermore, when I use SMTP authentication I have these next errors, on every device:

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: someemail@test.com Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: someemail@test.com
```

SMTP server error: Authentication failed

**UPDATE:**

Full errors resulted:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-sclabo15.ds.systemsunit.com ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 16 Mar 2016 13:10:25 +0200 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-sclabo15.ds.systemsunit.com Hello confidential.com [176.223.213.66] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect authentication data
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Reset OK
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:550 Authentication failed
SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 550 Authentication failed
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: confidential@confidential.com Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: confidential@confidential.com

SMTP server error: Authentication failed
```

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer and you need to read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and other docs. Your errors do not match your code - you can't be getting SMTP and auth errors when you're not using SMTP.

Comment: Tell me something I don't know. I already read the troubleshooting guide. Didin't helped. Otherwise I wouldn't come here to ask.

Comment: Read it again - you have not applied any of the things it suggests.

Comment: I've posted the original code I used. I tried steps like PHP 5.6 certificate verification failure and Using encryption, from the guide(and others). Had the same errors. And I'm using an older version of PHPMailer because I have an older version of PHP (5.3)

Comment: The code you have posted does not use SMTP. There's no point in trying random things like disabling certificate verification when that's not the error you're getting. We don't know what your problem is because you have not posted your full debug output, despite both one of the answers and the guide telling you to.

Comment: Okay @Synchro, I added the full error output. Does this help?

Comment: "Password not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect authentication data" seems pretty clear. The output does not match your code, and you're still using an old version of PHPMailer.

Comment: The password is correct 100%. What do you mean by the "output does not match your code"? And why should an older version of PHPMailer not work if it worked till now?

Comment: does the password use any non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @Martin, if '#' is non ASCII, then yes.

Comment: You may need to escape your password string then before giving it to PHPMailer but I'm not sure on this as an SMTP issue, but I suggest googling SMTP auth bugs, I have a few results on this search suggesting that SMTP contains issues with certain characters (such as # and @ )

Comment: link to an issue: https://meta.discourse.org/t/bug-smtp-password-field-does-not-escape-comment-sign-hash/23344/6

Comment: If possible I suggest retrying your atempts with a new password that does not contain a hash character. Also for protection google may (possibly, maybe) also be removing these sort of characters from incoming strings (if it's google mail you're relating to)

Comment: By "output does not match your code" I mean that your code is not set to use SMTP at all, yet you're using SMTP, i.e. the code you've posted is not the code you're running. SMTP has no problem with strange chars - passwords are usually base64-encoded, so it's all 7-bit safe - though mail servers can still have bugs. Are you sure you're connecting to the right server? Your (commented out) `Host` param is 'confidential.com' but you're connecting to a 'systemsunit.com' host.

Comment: That link to discourse is irrelevant - it describes a bug in discourse's config parser, nothing to do with SMTP - it's just where the bug happens to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the password use any non-ASCII characters? – Martin    @Martin,
>
> if '#' is non ASCII, then yes. - Anonymous

Your issue may be that your password contains the `#` character. This character is a bit of a pain as it doesn't quite fit as being "safe" but is often not actually removed or cleaned by many cleaning functions. It is a URL address special character and has repeatedly come up as being a cause for similar SMTP errors:

https://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/bugs/539/

https://meta.discourse.org/t/bug-smtp-password-field-does-not-escape-comment-sign-hash/23344/6

Also check your string encoding for the username and password strings. Your reference to `$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';` *might* be causing the PHPMailer to encode the password for the SMTP (I'm not sure though).

http://www.easy-smtp.com/smtp-troubleshooting-guide

There are also various other knock on events such as you will be blocked from the server for to many failed authentication attempts. Frustrating, but needs to be noted.

http://www.fehcom.de/qmail/smtpauth.html
http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm

**Solution:**
Debug and change your password to not contain the `#` character and see if that improves your situation. But please note your potential for being blocked for too many false logins and you'd need to wait some time for a clear connection to te SMTP server again.

Answer (score -1):

`$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` enables SMTP debug information (for testing)

Comment: I had $mail->SMTPDebug = 1 on